# Evolution du sens de livrer/délivrer à partir de "libre"

Tags: sens, usage, étymologie, latin, ancien-français

Comment les mot "délivrer" et "livrer" ont-t-il évolué, 
en partant de "rendre libre"
(sens de délivrer en vieux français: https://www.etymonline.com/word/deliver),

-pour donner "tendre à quelqu'un" (d'après etymonline *hand over*)
-et finalement signifier livrer par exemple un colis (qui est aussi le sens de l'anglais "to deliver")?

Comment: Il a **déjà** aussi ce sens en AF. Attesté au XIIé possiblement en raison des formalités liées à l'affranchissement d'esclaves / remises d'otages

Comment: Pourriez-vous en faire une réponse SVP? (et aussi me donner les références, je n'ai rien trouvé)

Comment: @aCOSwt  Oui, le premier sens de « livrer » (que seul « délivrer » a conservé) est « rendre libre » (directo du lat. *liberare* → « rendre libre », de *liber* → « libre » ) (960). L'emploi se diversifie pour signifier « mettre à la disposition de quelqu'un » au Xe s. et au XIIIe s.  « remettre à un acheteur ce qui a été commandé et payé ». *Libérer* n'est arrivé en français qu'au 15e s. issu aussi du latin *liberare* dérivé de *liber*. Le glissement de sens existait déjà en latin il me semble, et relié à l'esclavage.

Comment: @Quidam : Désolé mais comme je ne suis pas **certain** de ce que j'avance en tant que raison.Toute réponse sérieuse exigerait un gros travail de ma part. J'ai juste voulu donner une piste que je connaissais.

Comment: C'est aussi la faute de ce site, où on a peur de donner des réponses de peur d'être sanctionné.

Answer (score 4):

*Livreur* est déjà attesté dans le sens de livraison de marchandise dans le [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/livrer)
 (IXe au XVe)
Noter le *livreure* (s.f.) et le *livreor* qui doit lui être beaucoup plus ancien en raison de la précision des cas.

*Livrer* se rencontre aussi et dans ce même sens dans la Chanson de Roland (XIe) (*Pois, li livrat le bastun e le brief* (341))

Tout ça pour dire que le sens n'a sonc pas vraiment évolué depuis l'AF.
Comme le souligne @Laure en commentaires de l'OP, l'étymon latin portait déjà ces deux sens possiblement pour la raison que j'ai donnée en commentaires de l'OP.