# Meaning of libérer and délivrer

Tags: synonymes

What are the differences in meaning, if any, between

> La police a libéré les otages. VS La police a délivré les otages.

Ibid.

> Les otages ont été libérés par la police. VS Les otages ont été délivrés par la police.

Ibid.

> Les otages se sont libérés. VS Les otages se sont délivrés.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nuance :
**délivrer** may be used for the police whereas **libérer** can be used for both police (set free) or kidnappers (let go).

So as long as you speak of the law enforcement only, your first two sentences have the same meaning.
I would personally prefer **délivrer** though, as it is more specific in this case.

The last sentence is different because **se délivrer** is rarely used compared to **se libérer**.

---

Il y a une nuance :
**délivrer** peut s'utiliser pour la police alors que **libérer** peut se dire aussi bien pour la libération par les ravisseurs (laisser partir), que par les policiers.

Donc si on ne parle que de policiers, les deux premières phrases ont le même sens. Personnellement, j'utiliserais plutôt **délivrer** qui est plus spécifique dans ce cas.

La dernière phrase est différente car **se délivrer** est beaucoup plus rare que **se libérer**.

Answer (score 2):

Libérer indique un changement d’état, on passe de l’état prisonnier à l’état libre, sans marquer l’origine de ce changement de situation.
Délivrer (délivrés) indique une intervention extérieure pour provoquer ce changement.
« Les otages ont été libérés «  n’indique pas de quelle façon cela s’est produit (ravisseurs ou intervention extérieure ou....)
« Les otages ont été délivrés «intervention extérieure uniquement - sous entendu par tel ou tel intervenant opposé aux ravisseurs «

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent in these sentences but that doesn't mean they are always interchangeable.

See:

- [Evolution du sens de livrer/délivrer à partir de "libre"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40254)
- [«Libérée, Délivrée» Comment comprendre cette phrase?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23881)
- [« Livrer un discours » au propre pour « prononcer (un discours) » est-il un emploi fautif ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/livrer-un-discours-au-propre-pour-prononcer-un-discours-est-il-un-empl)